# How to execute a system call in python using PyCharm on Debian Linux?

Tags: python, path, pycharm, system

I am not able to run a system call using PyCharm and can't figure out what variables or environment settings to change.

Given this simple script:

```
import os
cmd = 'ifconfig -a'
os.system(cmd)
```

...which runs fine at the command line in terminal, yields the following error:

```
sh: ifconfig: command not found
```

This is happening with really any process I'm trying to run such as CSVSQL, PSQL, etc.

**I have tried:** Displaying my python interpreter paths dispayed at the command line, I tried adding them to the PyCharm interpreter paths, to no avail.

There are several other threads out there describing similar problems, but there doesn't seem to be a good solution that I have come across.

I'm running Linux Mint 19, though this works on my Windows installation (PATH output is much different).

My apologies if this is really simple... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `printenv` on both Python and terminal, and check the `PATH` variable. Use `os.environ['PATH'] = 'My path'` to set it to what you saw on the terminal.

For future issues (That I've run into):

A quick way to check if it's an exported environment variable is to run `os.system("/bin/sh -c \"MYCMD\"")`, and then run the same `"/bin/sh -c \"MYCMD\""` string in your terminal. If there's still a problem, then it must be an export (And this is the likely issue).

To resolve this, try `printenv` in both python and the terminal to see the list of exports. You should see a discrepancy. The format is simple as you can simple copy the output of the terminal's `printenv` (Which should be a series of `declare`s), and paste it into python so python will get the same variables. Then your "/bin/sh CMD" calls should align.

The wrapped `/bin/sh` is in case they're running different shells or have different local variables. `echo $SHELL` can confirm this, at which point you can compare `set`s *and* `printenv`s and copy paste in the same way. Wrapped you only have to compare exports, as that's what get passed to child processes.

Comment: I see the discrepancies between the two, and I guess that is the same issue I've tried to solve in PyCharm as in my original question... where do I paste the exports as you've suggested? Thanks for your response!

Comment: just did a reinstall and things are working - printenv is showing all the locations i need... thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy it worked out. You can change the environment variables in `os.environ` for each key (PATH being the important one), or use it before your system calls. (`os.system(printenv + shellscript)`, with `printenv` being a string containing the terminal `printenv output`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pycharm isn't getting the PATH from your profile or rc. Try giving the absolute path of the command.

`import os
 cmd = '/sbin/ifconfig -a'
 os.system(cmd)`

You can also verify your path using following.

`print(os.environ['PATH'])`

And use following to add your custom path to current env path.

`os.environ['PATH'] += ':/sbin'`

Comment: If I run that, I get: sh: /sbin/ifconfig: No such file or directory

Comment: @DPSSpatial Try `whereis ifconfig` on your terminal, and use that.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone its in that spot... even without the arguments I still get an error. Very weird...!!!

Comment: @DPSSpatial Try `echo $SHELL` and `pwd` to get your bearings. Also try `ls /` to see if you at least get the root directory.

Comment: @DPSSpatial in your she&#39;ll can you run &quot; ls -l `which ifconfig`&quot; and check if you have the exact path and executable permissions on the binary? Also make sure you are able to run ifconfig -a on the system where you are trying to run the script. And assuming it is Linux.

Comment: @stingray from pycharm, running which ifconfig yields: which: no ifconfig in (/app/bin:/usr/bin) - all the scripts i'm writing all work at the command line on the same machine. Thanks again!!

Comment: @stingray just did a reinstall and things are working - printenv is showing all the locations i need... thank you for your help!